# Having trouble vertical align and absolute positioned div in a height: auto container

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to vertically align a block of text within an absolute positioned div that's over an image with a max-width of 100% and a height of auto (it's for a responsive layout). How can I vertically align the block of text so it retains it's vertical alignment throughout scaling? I suspect I'll need to use some sort of javascript, but I'm not sure. Any help is greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Jjs8/

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide">
                <img src="http://awsassets.panda.org/img/scr_239815_362780.jpg" class="image">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="caption-inside">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    max-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.slider {
    position: relaitve:
    width: 100%;
}

ul.slides {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li.slide {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div.caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.caption-inside {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you part of the way, but the height will play as a problem.

```
div.caption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I know there is some new CSS features that are going to make all of this a lot easier, but for now you might have to live with the restrictions or turn to js.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yep, that solution does work until the height of the image beings to adjust. Can you give me a few hints on the javascript? I'm not even sure where to begin with it. Thanks again.